# php echo button won't call modal (materialize)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, materialize

I have ajax that calls a php function that populates my table. But whenever I would click the `Edit` button in my table, the modal doesn't show up. I've tried calling the modal normally on a test button with the same code as my php echo'ed button and it works normally. 
I also tried replacing the `href` with `onclick` but still it won't work.

Test button that worked (same code with php echo'ed button):

```
<button id="" class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light btn orange lighten-1" href="#modal1">Edit</button>
```

Modal:

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['taskDate'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['taskName'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['taskType'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['duration'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['startTime'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row['endTime'].'</td>';
    echo    '<td> <button id="'.$row['taskId'].'" class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light btn orange lighten-1" href="#modal1">Edit</button> </td>';
    echo    '<td> <button id="'.$row['taskId'].'" class="waves-effect waves-light btn red lighten-1">Delete</button> </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

I don't know what I'm missing here. I think it's something on my php code since the test button works.

Thanks for anyone that can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just solved my own problem.

I've used version 0.98.0 (was 0.97.0) of materialize js. Then used `data-target` instead of `href` and it magically worked!

Old Code:

```
'<td> <button id="'.$row['taskId'].'" class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light btn orange lighten-1" href="#modal1">Edit</button> </td>';
```

New Code:

```
'<td> <button id="'.$row['taskId'].'" class="waves-effect waves-light btn orange lighten-1" data-target="editModal">Edit</button> </td>';
```